# I get SSIS Error code: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager Oracle Connection Manager failed with error code 0x80004005

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I'm building a new SSIS package to export data from an Oracle database into a SQL database but I'm getting errors when I try to execute the task in SSIS.

[image: Error]
[image: ExecutionResults]

I've installed the 32bit and 64 bit connector for Oracle
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55179

and the SQL Server 2017: Microsoft Connector Version 5.0 for Oracle by Attunity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver15

I've set the Run64BitRuntime to False
I've checked the connection in the connection manager

[image: Connection]

and also can preview the data.

[image: preview]

I'm a complete newbie using Oracle and still learning SSIS so any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your package/project protection level? You need to check **DontSaveSensitive** settings. https://bageshkumarbagi-msbi.blogspot.com/2018/10/dontsavesensitive-protection-level-in.html

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I've read your blog and played around with the DontSaveSensitive settings and changing it to DontSaveSensitive gives different errors but still doesn't work. It was originally on EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey.